# Django templates - get list of multiple GET param

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a url with multiple GET params (of the same name) - `mycompany.com/?a=1&a=2`

When i do in django template:

```
{{ request.GET }}
```

I get:

```
<QueryDict: {'a': ['1', '2']}>
```

When i do in django template:

```
{{ request.GET.a }}
```

I get:

```
2
```

When i try to loop:

```
{% for a in request.GET.a %}
    {{ a }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get:

```
2
```

---

How to make behave multiple GET params as list in django templates? Thx!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Template filter:**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_list(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.getlist(key)
```

**Templates:**

```
{% for a in request.GET|get_list:'a' %}
    {{ a }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Template filter:**
[app/templatetags/**exampletag**.py]

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dict(dictionary).get(key)
```

**Templates:**

```
{% load exampletag %}

{{ request.GET|get_item:'a' }}
```

[How to: Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @xyres, what is wrong? Just use template filter to make QueryDict behave like a normal dict.

Answer (score 1):

A bit wonky, but does the job:

```
{%for list_of_elements in request.GET.lists%}
    {%for element in list_of_elements.1%}
        {{ element }}
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

Or if you only want a specific list from the query:

```
{%for list_of_elements in request.GET.lists %}
    {%if list_of_elements.0 == "a"%}
        {%for element in list_of_elements.1%}
            {{ element }}
        {%endfor%}
    {%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for name, values in request.GET.lists %}
    {% if name == 'a' %}{{ values|join:", " }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for name, values in request.GET.lists %}
    {% if name == 'a' %} 
        {% for value in values %}{{ value }}{% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```